# Cannot get Emscripten path, please specify it either by EMSCRIPTEN environment variable or --emscripten_dir option(opencv.js build error)

Tags: opencv, compiler-errors

I am totally new for opencv.js.I have some problems on building opencv.js
I am using Windows 10.I follow below steps for setup opencv.js

https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d4/da1/tutorial_js_setup.html

1-)First I used below link to download the Empscripten 
https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/getting_started/downloads.html#sdk-installation-instructions

2-)And execute this line son command propmpt(in empscripten folder)

```
 emsdk
 emsdk_env.bat
```

After this Execution , Empscripten set the path

```
EMSDK = C:/Users/q/Desktop/web/opencv.js/emsdk-portable-64bit
EM_CONFIG = C:\Users\q\.emscripten
```

3-)Download phyton 3

4-)Clone opencv

```
git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
```

5-)Execute this code to build opencv.js but i get this error

```
python C:\Users\q\opencv\platforms\js\build_js.py C:\OpencvJS

Error:
Cannot get Emscripten path, please specify it either by EMSCRIPTEN environment variable or --emscripten_dir option.
```

The problem look like "EMPSCRİPTEN cannot set the path properly and part 5 fail to execute".How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

```
export EMSCRIPTEN=~/path_to_emsdk/emsdk/upstream/emscripten
```

Answer (score 0):

on linux 
i run

```sh
# Clone, pull, and build the latest "sdk" Emscripten environment
./emsdk install sdk-incoming-64bit

# Set the "incoming SDK" as the active version.
./emsdk activate sdk-incoming-64bit
```

then run

```sh
source ./emsdk_env.sh
```

emsdk require tool and sdk 
this script helped me, you can have a try